# ReactJS PreventDefault when already passing parameter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

My `onClick` button is calling the function `getUserInput(i, event)`, however, since the `onClick` event is bound (`bind`) to `(this, id)`, I can't understand how I will pass the over "event" parameter?

Function:

```
getUserInput = (i, event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const searchLocation = document.getElementById(i).value;
    this.state.locationArray[i].location = searchLocation;
    this.setState({
        locationArray: this.state.locationArray
    })
    this.createGrid();
}
```

Button:

```
<form className="form" role="search" autoComplete="off">
      <input id={id} className="searchBar" type="search" name="searchField" placeholder={filledArray[i].name}></input>
      <button onClick={this.getUserInput.bind(this, id)} value="submit" className="searchButton"><i className="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: That should work as written above. You'll receive the `id` has `i` and the event object will follow it as the value of the second parameter. Simpler example: `var f2 = f1.bind(this, "a"); f2("b");` results in `f1` being called with the arguments `"a", "b"`. Is it not working for you? If so, please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind` return a new function by adding the parameters passed to it at the beginning followed by the default parameters and binding the function to the correct context and hence when you write

```
onClick={this.getUserInput.bind(this, id)}
```

`getUserInput` receives id as the first parameter and the default parameters i.e event as the second so you don't need to pass it explicitly

A typical implementation of `bind` function would be

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context){
    var that = this,
        slicedArgs = Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 1),
        bounded = function (){
            var newArgs = slicedArgs.concat(Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments, 0));
            return that.apply(context,newArgs);
        }
    bounded.prototype = that.prototype;
    return bounded;
}
```

Comment: Since the OP's code as shown would work, there's no question to answer here (yet).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, the OP code works, but from what it seems from the question OP wants to understand how he can pass event or how is getUserInput receiving it already

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This is the correct answer. I did not get that event was called as a default parameter. I was trying to insert it into the parameterlist when calling the function. Thank you!